# How to conditionally format column numbers

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

[image]How i can format the column so that integers won't have decimals ?

Comment: Try this 
https://superuser.com/questions/205759/format-a-number-with-optional-decimal-places-in-excel

Comment: I am currently using the following code line to format the entire column is it possible to do the same or i need to use some array ?

Worksheets("Open SO").Columns("N").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"

Answer (score 0):

```
r-click the cell > format cells > Number Tab : Number > Decimal place.
```

That should do. ( :